# Parse.com preventing player from rating level multiply times

Tags: java, cloud, parse-platform

I am using parse.com cloud storage, to implement level sharing/downloading and rating for built in level editor for my game, so players are allowed to built and test their own created levels, latter on they can share it with different players, that`s how I upload it to the parse.com cloud storage:

```
        ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("Levels");
        testObject.put("file", new ParseFile(name + ".lvl", levelString.getBytes()));
        testObject.put("author", authorName);
        testObject.put("email", authorEmail);
        testObject.saveInBackground();
```

It works fine, but I wanted to let players also rate downloaded levels (lets say 1-5 stars) it could be simple, by creating new two fields called rating and ratings count, so every time someone will vote, I would add it to ratings count and would ++ ratings count.

Problem is, how to prevent player from rating particular level multiple times? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have thought about this for a project of mine. In the end you will need two data points.

1. You need to track the counts per rank on the object (Level in your case)
2. You need to track UserLevelRating, at minimum a reference to the user, reference to the target (Level), and the rating given (if you will let people change ratings)

Depending on how you want to implement it, to prevent rating something twice, or to allow people to change the rating they have given something, you would do a query for the current user and the Level. If a record is returned they have already voted, so prevent them from voting again.

You could add some cloud code using before-safe or after-save logic to handle other things, such as changing the vote and updating the counts on the target (Level).

Here's a sample of the logic I would use for a simple single vote system without changing votes:

- Test for existence of UserLevelRating record, if it exists prevent voting
- Saving vote, include User=current user, Level=selected level, Rating=stars given
- Cloud code, in after-save of UserLevelRating, looks at Level property, loads the level, calls increment on the property for the rating (e.g. if Rating=3, increment("Stars3") would be called)

Anytime you load a Level object you would have counts for each rating, and could produce the average.